# Day of week in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I've spent the entire day trying to figure out how to use power query to get a day of week in my date table and cant figure it out.

It shouldnt be text as when placed on a graph it should sort as mon, tue,wed, thu, fri sat, sun. Similarly, looking for this to be within months. i.e Jan,Feb Mar....

I tried #"Inserted Day Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day", "Day Name", each Date.DayOfWeekName.monday([Date]), type text), but it displays a number as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6...I could settle for this however would prefer a day 7 rather than zero.

Mon needs to be 1st day of the week. thanks in advance

Comment: Did either of these two responses answer your question?

Comment: Day of Week Name = FORMAT('calendar'[Date],"dddd")
https://radacad.com/get-the-day-of-the-week-name-and-number-in-power-bi-using-dax

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, if the date is in Column1, add column, custom column with formula

To get Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

```
= Date.DayOfWeekName([Column1])
```

To get Mon, Tue, Wed

```
= Text.Start(Date.DayOfWeekName([Column1]),3)
```

To get a number, where Mon=1 and Sunday=7

```
= 1+Date.DayOfWeek([Column1],Day.Monday)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Show day as three letters and sort the day by day number considering Monday to be 1 you can create a new table under data view using the below query then sort the "Day" on the "Day Num" from data view

```
_Calendar = ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDAR("01-Jan-2023","31-Dec-2025"),"Month Year",FORMAT([Date],"MMM YYYY"), "Year",YEAR([Date]),"WeekNum",WEEKNUM([Date],2),"Day", FORMAT([Date],"DDD"),"Day Num",WEEKDAY([Date],2))
```

Note: Date provided on the above code is just an example